# Is the Torgue DLC included in the Season Pass?

Tags: borderlands-2

I know the Mechromancer DLC is not included, but is the Mr. Torgue campaign of Carnage included in the Season Pass? Or is it separate like the Mechromancer?

Comment: on a side note i just saw the information on steam store, I was looking at greenmangaming.com before that and this wasn't stated.

Comment: All DLC except the Mechromancer is included. The Mechromancer isn't because it was a pre-order incentive.

Comment: an add on question to this. it is described that there are playable characters in the Torgue DLC. i just downloaded it but have yet to play it. i just bought borderlands 2 so yea. can someone enlighten me on this.

Comment: I've not completed every side quest yet, but so far no. There are some new NPCs, and Mr Torgue is genius funny, but no more playable characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is included, along with the already available *Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty* DLC and two yet unannounced packs.

Comment: I see.. thanks for the reply cuz I was reading the Season Pass but there wasn't any mentioned, but in the Captain Scarlett it was written that it was included.

Comment: When a new DLC comes up, you can tell if it is gonna be included by its description - a Season Pass includes four **Campaign** DLCs. Mechromancer is not campaign-related.

Answer (score 1):

when you purchase the season pass for 2400 microsoft points, your basically purchasing all 4 dlc's, 
your paying for 3 and getting one free, 
otherwise individually its 800 microsoft points for each dlc, which will add to 3200 M points in total.

Just putting it into writing.

Hope it helps some people :-)

Comment: thumbs up, thanks but i am playing it on PC :D